# Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies occurs when response resources are added for 4xx and 5xx errors

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

In our serverless app, we have added the following to the resources block of serverless.yml so that 4xx and 5xx error responses have CORS headers.

```yaml
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'

    GatewayResponseDefault5XX:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_5XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
```

This worked for us until recently, but now It causes the following error when trying to deploy the app using `serverless deploy`. This error goes away when we deploy the app, removing the above resources from our `serverless.yml`.

```
The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ApiGatewayResourceViewer, ApiGatewayRestApi] in the Resources block of the template.
```

But the problem is these resources are required for us to successfully catch 4xx and 5xx errors returning from the app. We can't just remove those and proceed.

**Is there any way to keep these resources and still deploy our app without errors?** Helpful suggestions are highly appreciated.

### ***Background information***

`serverless-plugin-split-stacks` configuration:

```yaml
custom:
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: false
    perType: true
    perGroupFunction: false
```

`serverless -v` output:

```sh
Framework Core: 2.15.0
Plugin: 4.4.2
SDK: 2.3.2
Components: 3.4.7
```

Comment: We eventually got rid of this error by uninstalling `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` and cleaning up the nested CloudFormation stacks created.